# Change MySQL value via email

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I have a `PHP/HTML` form which stores values to MySQL database.
I do the insert execution

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO hotel_nights 
  (name, attribute, hotel, availability, cost, date_in, date_out, stays, people, rooms, note, user) 
VALUES 
  ('$name', '$attribute', '$hotel', '$availability', '$cost', '$date_in', '$date_out', '$stays', '$people', '$rooms', '$note', '$user')
";
```

and then I send an approval email via `phpmail`.

Is there any way on approval email to have links/action buttons which will change one MySQL field value? A yes or no case where will change value to 1 or 0

Comment: Sure, you can add a link that goes to your site and does whatever you want it to do

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

In phpmailer (i think taht what you use) you can add html and inside the html you can make link to send to your site with confirm button when clicked the value changes like:

```php
$mail->Body = '<p>Please click to confirm 
<a href="http://yoursite.com/page/action?email='.$email.'">http://yoursite.com/page/action?email=' . $email. '</a>
</p>';
```

i think that is the solution for your problem (there is more ways to do it)
Hope i was clear